# Using C# Variables in SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm very new to this. There might be something obvious I'm completely missing, but...

When making an SQL query (ASP.NET with C#) I can get this:

```
var query = db.Query("SELECT * FROM pageinfo WHERE pageID = 1");
```

to work, and yet this:

```
var pageID=1;
var query = db.Query("SELECT * FROM pageinfo WHERE pageID = @pageID");
```

does not.

Basically, all I want to do is place a variable into the query. Is there some special syntax for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: @user2124495 you will end up in Sql Injection. please use parametrized queries

Answer (score 15):

> Is there some special syntax for doing this?

Yes, Use [SQLParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pageinfo WHERE pageID = @pageID");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageID", 2);
```

Your current method `db.Query` seems to be a your own implementation. You can overload that method to receive a list of `SqlParameter` and then add those parameters to your command. This will prevent you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks! Got that to work now, but now that I don't have the 'query' variable, how would I get the result?

Comment: You can either use [SqlDataReader to read data](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04) or [Populate a DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx) from command

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageID=1;
var query = db.Query("SELECT * FROM pageinfo WHERE pageID = '"+ PAGEid +"');
```

Comment: **Don't**. Read more about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)